# In my project when I import `Ionic/core` it overwrites my scss styling

Tags: css, sass, web-component, stenciljs

### What I am trying to do in stencilJs:

Basically I am trying to build a wheel time picker which have 3 columns for hour in 12h format and minutes which depends on the what type of array is provided for example: `[0,15,30,45]` or `[00,30]`
with `am` and `pm` as a 3rd column to choose from , and if user provides anytime it should use that as default value and emit an event on update, and this wheel will do that all on scroll or touch

so to do that, I am using `ion-datetime` component but

### My Problem:

When I use `ion-datetime` component in my project and after importing `@ionic/core` in my .tsx file it overwrites all my custom scss
importing `@ionic/core` messes up the whole style and style of other web component in my project as well.

### What I tried

I tried adding `globalStyles` to my `stencil.config` file, even used different class name so thy don't clash with each other and I am using the latest version of ionic/core.
If anyone have any idea or suggestion or working example, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

**Why it's happening :**

because `Host` of `ion-datetime` is `overwriting` the `Host` of my other web components

**Solution**

You can define `Host` again with !important to make your style priority in your own web component
To know how you can work with `Host`  you can refer to their docs
https://stenciljs.com/docs/styling

or better solution instead of using NPM package @ionic/core in stencil you can use the CDN link

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

because you may have multiple CSS style in your web component and re defining them all is not possible sometimes